# Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $5^p+ 4p^4$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

> Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $5^p+ 4p^4$ is a perfect square.

Comment: $p=5$ is a solution. Did you really try?

Comment: How hard did you search? $p=5$ works.

Comment: As a way to get started:  Note that $5^p+4p^4=n^2\implies 5^p=(n-2p^2)(n+2p^2)$ so both of the factors on the right must be powers of $5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$5$ is the only such prime. Note that if
$$5^p+4p^4=n^2$$
Then
$$5^p=(n+2p^2)(n-2p^2)$$
Each factor must be a power of $5$, hence the difference of the factors is a multiple of $5$ unless $5^p=4p^2+1$. If this is not the case, then this difference is $4p^2$ and a multiple of $5$, so $p$ is a multiple of $5$. Since it is prime, $p=5$.

Otherwise, since $p^2>1$ we have $5p^2>5^p$, so $p^2>5^{p-1}$. By induction we can prove that this entails that $p<5$, so this is impossible to satisfy given the conditions.

Comment: What if one of the factors equals $\pm1$?

Comment: @Serv It can't be $-1$, but it could be $1$. Let me think about that case.

Comment: @Serva See my edit.