# Prime numbers & perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

Find all prime numbers such that $2p^4-p^2+16$ is a perfect square.

$2p^4-p^2+16=n^2$

$16-n^2=p^2-2p^4$

$(4-n)(4+n)=p^2(1-2p^2)$

What should I do next?

Comment: Either $p \mid 4+n$ or $p \mid 4-n.$ But $p$:cannot divide both of them. For otherwise $p \mid 8 \implies p=2.$ But then $2p^4 - p^2 + 16 = 44,$ which is not a perfect square. This shows that either $p^2 \mid 4+n$ or $p^2 \mid 4-n.$

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194897/find-all-prime-numbers-p-such-that-5p-4p4-is-a-perfect-square#comment6574976_3194897), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580363/find-all-primes-p-such-that-p3-4p9-is-a-perfect-square?rq=1).

Comment: $p=3$ so that $2p^4-p^2+16=13^2$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde can you please check my solution below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that for $p>3$ we have $$p \equiv 1\ \text {or}\ 2\ (\text {mod}\ 3).$$

Let for $p>3$ $\exists$ $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $$2p^4-p^2+16  = k^2.$$ But then $$2p^4-p^2+16 \equiv 2\ \not\equiv 0\ \text {or}\ 1 \equiv k^2\ (\text {mod}\ 3).$$

So $p=3$ is the only solution.

Comment: How did you conclude that 2p^4−p^2+16≡2(mod 3)? Did you just check for the next few primes?

Comment: Because if $p \equiv 1\ \text {or}\ 2\ (\text {mod}\ 3)$ then $p^2 \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 3)$ and hence $p^4 \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 3).$ So we have $$\begin{align*} 2p^4-p^2 + 16 & \equiv 2.1 - 1 + 16\ (\text {mod}\ 3). \\ & \equiv 17\ (\text {mod}\ 3). \\ & \equiv 2\ (\text {mod}\ 3). \end{align*}$$ Hope it will help.